# Electron secondary window doesn't load HTML file

Tags: node.js, electron

I am extending Wexond, a Web browser that can be found on GitHub here https://github.com/wexond/browser-base.
The problem is that I have integrated a side pane containing a bunch of buttons.
One of these buttons, if clicked, should show a modal secondary window with some static HTML in it.
However, when that button is clicked, the secondary window gets shown, but it doesn't contain the HTML that is loaded. It is blank.

Here is my AppWindow class (to make it quicker for you to read the important parts - be aware that **secondaryWindow** is what I am talking about. It is initialized in the constructor of the class):

```
// All the requrired import statements
//...

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

export class AppWindow {
  public win: BrowserWindow;

  public secondaryWindow: BrowserWindow;

  public viewManager: ViewManager;

  public incognito: boolean;

  public constructor(incognito: boolean) {
    this.win = new BrowserWindow({
      frame: false,
      minWidth: 400,
      minHeight: 450,
      width: 900,
      height: 700,
      titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      webPreferences: {
        plugins: true,
        // TODO: enable sandbox, contextIsolation and disable nodeIntegration to improve security
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        javascript: true,
        // TODO: get rid of the remote module in renderers
        enableRemoteModule: true,
      },
      icon: resolve(
        app.getAppPath(),
        `static/${isNightly ? 'nightly-icons' : 'icons'}/icon.png`,
      ),
      show: false,
    });

    this.secondaryWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width:600,
      height:300,
      webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true },
      parent: this.win,
      modal: true,
      show: false
    });
    this.secondaryWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'sec-wind.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));
    
    ipcMain.on('show-QandA-win', (e, args) => {
      this.secondaryWindow.show();
    })
    // TODO dont destroy window when clicking on 'x'. Hide it.

    this.incognito = incognito;

    this.viewManager = new ViewManager(this, incognito);

    runMessagingService(this);

    const windowDataPath = getPath('window-data.json');

    let windowState: any = {};

    (async () => {
      try {
        // Read the last window state from file.
        windowState = JSON.parse(
          await promises.readFile(windowDataPath, 'utf8'),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        await promises.writeFile(windowDataPath, JSON.stringify({}));
      }

      // Merge bounds from the last window state to the current window options.
      if (windowState) {
        this.win.setBounds({ ...windowState.bounds });
      }

      if (windowState) {
        if (windowState.maximized) {
          this.win.maximize();
        }
        if (windowState.fullscreen) {
          this.win.setFullScreen(true);
        }
      }
    })();

    this.win.show();

    // Update window bounds on resize and on move when window is not maximized.
    this.win.on('resize', () => {
      if (!this.win.isMaximized()) {
        windowState.bounds = this.win.getBounds();
      }
    });

    this.win.on('move', () => {
      if (!this.win.isMaximized()) {
        windowState.bounds = this.win.getBounds();
      }
    });

    const resize = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (process.platform === 'linux') {
          this.viewManager.select(this.viewManager.selectedId, false);
        } else {
          this.viewManager.fixBounds();
        }
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.webContents.send('tabs-resize');
      }, 500);

      this.webContents.send('tabs-resize');
    };

    this.win.on('maximize', resize);
    this.win.on('restore', resize);
    this.win.on('unmaximize', resize);

    this.win.on('close', (event: Electron.Event) => {
      const { object: settings } = Application.instance.settings;

      if (settings.warnOnQuit && this.viewManager.views.size > 1) {
        const answer = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, {
          type: 'question',
          title: `Quit ${app.name}?`,
          message: `Quit ${app.name}?`,
          detail: `You have ${this.viewManager.views.size} tabs open.`,
          buttons: ['Close', 'Cancel'],
        });

        if (answer === 1) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
      }

      // Save current window state to a file.
      windowState.maximized = this.win.isMaximized();
      windowState.fullscreen = this.win.isFullScreen();
      writeFileSync(windowDataPath, JSON.stringify(windowState));

      this.win.setBrowserView(null);

      this.viewManager.clear();

      if (Application.instance.windows.list.length === 1) {
        Application.instance.dialogs.destroy();
      }

      if (
        incognito &&
        Application.instance.windows.list.filter((x) => x.incognito).length ===
          1
      ) {
        Application.instance.sessions.clearCache('incognito');
        Application.instance.sessions.unloadIncognitoExtensions();
      }

      Application.instance.windows.list = Application.instance.windows.list.filter(
        (x) => x.win.id !== this.win.id,
      );
    });

    // this.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      this.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });
      this.win.loadURL('http://localhost:4444/app.html');
    } else {
      this.win.loadURL(join('file://', app.getAppPath(), 'build/app.html'));
    }

    this.win.on('enter-full-screen', () => {
      this.send('fullscreen', true);
      this.viewManager.fixBounds();
    });

    this.win.on('leave-full-screen', () => {
      this.send('fullscreen', false);
      this.viewManager.fixBounds();
    });

    this.win.on('enter-html-full-screen', () => {
      this.viewManager.fullscreen = true;
      this.send('html-fullscreen', true);
    });

    this.win.on('leave-html-full-screen', () => {
      this.viewManager.fullscreen = false;
      this.send('html-fullscreen', false);
    });

    this.win.on('scroll-touch-begin', () => {
      this.send('scroll-touch-begin');
    });

    this.win.on('scroll-touch-end', () => {
      this.viewManager.selected.send('scroll-touch-end');
      this.send('scroll-touch-end');
    });

    this.win.on('focus', () => {
      Application.instance.windows.current = this;
    });
  }
```

The structure of the project is :

```
src
|-common
|-constants
|-interfaces
|-models
|-preloads
|-renderer
|-utils
|-main
    |- dialogs
    |- ...
    |- windows
         |- app.ts          <--
         |- index.ts
         |- sec-wind.html   <--
```

The AppWindow class is exported from location src/main/windows/app.ts, and the html file is at location src/main/windows/sec-win.html (indicated by the two arrows).

Then the code is run via an rpm script that first builds the project.

Any idea? Might that be because of the built? What info should I post to better debug this?

**P.S.**
.loadUrl() and .loadFile() give the same result.

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments, here I am posting a picture of my devTools containing the warnings I get:
[image]

However, I can't see that package being required anywhere in the source code.

Comment: If you open the dev tools of the window, do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: I see a couple of warnings, but they seem to be unrelated, as if I comment out the files and codes containing the secondaryWindow instance those warnings stay.

Comment: @aabuhijleh I have updated my question to include a screen of my warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research I realised that the html file I was attempting to load was in my source code folder, but the current working directory specified in the lock.json file was build/.

build/ contained all the compiled code that the app needed to run. So I just copied my html file into that folder.

I did so by changing my webpack.base.js configurationand to included this :

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const preloadConfig = getConfig({
  target: 'electron-renderer',

  devtool: false,

  watch: dev,

  entry: {
    'view-preload': './src/preloads/view-preload',
  },
  // Here in plugin you can specify what you want to copy in the build/ folder.
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: join(__dirname, "src", "preloads", "QandA", "templates"),
          to: "QandA/templates",
          toType: "dir",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
},);

module.exports = preloadConfig
```

This script copies all the files in src/preloads/QandA/templates (where my html file was) to a new location in build/ namely QandA/templates.

After that I just changed the url of the file I wanted to load to :

```
this.secondaryWindow.webContents.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'QandA', 'templates', 'QandA.html'));
```

Answer (score -1):

as it is very strange for me like electron `loadFile` is not working in this case. cz, windows.loadFile is working fine for me in every case.

```
this.secondaryWindow.loadFile(path.join('./sec-wind.html'));
```

Comment: This isn't trying to answer the question and is better off as a comment instead